# How do I send multiple headers with angularJS resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Trying to send multiple headers in the same request with angularJS this is what I have...

```
var auth = $resource("",
        {},
        {
          GetUserDetails: {
            url: Config.api.user.details(),
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false,
            cache: false,
            headers: ["xx:xx","ff:ff"]
          }
        });
```

But the request just shows...

```
0:xx:xx
1:ff:ff
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
```

Anyone know the right data structure to send a collection of headers down in the headers property on the resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage):

> headers – {Object} – Map of strings or functions which return strings representing HTTP headers to send to the server. If the return value of a function is null, the header will not be sent.

So what you need is:

```
headers: {
    headerName1: 'headerValue1',
    headerName2: 'headerValue2'
}
```

Comment: Documentation? what's one of them then? :-)

Thanks dude, I did look but didn't see it. Although looking...

"Map of strings or functions" - I will have to learn what a map is in this case!

Thanks will mark as correct as soon as 8 mins is up!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it up as

```
var auth = $resource("",
    {},
    {
      GetUserDetails: {
        url: Config.api.user.details(),
        method: 'POST',
        isArray: false,
        cache: false,
        headers: [{'xx':'xx'},{'ff':'ff'}]
      }
    });
```